# Do mutual funds get interest on the cash positions in their portfolio?

Tags: mutual-funds, interest-rate, interest, cash

I am writing a paper about mutual funds and I was wondering if mutual funds get paid interest on the cash positions they have in their portfolio. If so, what kind of rate would this be?

Do funds use e.g. 1-month T-bills? Are these liquid enough such that the fund can still accommodate inflows and outflows or exploit short-term opportunities?

If possible, please provide sources. Thank you!

Comment: If available, perhaps a fund's financial statements might provide this?

Comment: T-bills are marketable, and _highly_ liquid. Anyone (including a fund) can easily hold for one day if that's what is needed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Which maturity T-Bills do you think mutual funds would trade? 1-month? Are there any lower maturities?

Comment: Normal, scheduled T-bills can be 4,8,13,26, or 52 weeks. (There are also 'cash management' bills which can be only a few days, but their supply is erratic depending on variations in Treasury's cash balance.) Anyone wanting 'cash-like' behavior would want bills with short _remaining_ term, but that could be either a newly-auctioned 4-week or a 26-week that was auctioned 22 weeks ago; these are economically equivalent and trade the same in the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cash position in mutual funds are usually disclosed as short-term reserves and can be invested in money market funds that earned about 2% return, while providing same liquidity as cash. However, I would say the percentage of return varies depends on the type of money market funds.

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/mutual_fund_cash_level.asp